# Append another validation function to Javascript form validation logic

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form that contains some field for user input.In this form I have Asp.net validation controls for each input controls . some of validators are custom validators that are used to handle internal validation logic in related JavaScript function. 
now I want to make sure form is valid when form onsubmit event is fired use following code:

```
form = documet.forms[0];

 form.onsubmit=function(){

 if(validMobile){
  return true;
 }
 return false;

}
```

Now , if I click on submit button if validmobile is true then always return true and form always post to server and other validations does not get fired ever.
Is there a way for me to take the validation of the form and then check the customize validation logic ?
for example :

```
form = documet.forms[0];

 form.onsubmit=function(){

 if(<b><u>form.isvalid</u></b> && validMobile){
  return true; 
 }
 return false; 

}
```

Comment: For **JS**: `Page_ClientValidate()`
For **C#**: `Page.IsValid`

Comment: can you explain  your comment?

Comment: if you want to check the page validation status from JS, you can you Page_ClientValidate() function for example you can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548546/page-clientvalidate-question

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement leaves the function when it's called. So you should not call it unless you are sure all tests were made.

Using a flag `isValid`, for example, you can keep track of whether or not one of your validations failed.

After you went through all validations, you can return that boolean value instead of a fixed one.

```
form = documet.forms[0];

form.onsubmit = function(){
    var isValid = true;

    if(!validMobile){
        isValid = false;
    } else if(!validDesktop) {
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```